# If a chicken has released a lot of moisture due to freezing, will these cause soup water to flow back in due to pore enlargement?

Tags: chicken, freezing, marinade

If you have slow freezed chicken and noticed a lot of water has come out, you then cook a soup, would the freezing have caused pores to enlarge and will the soup water/marinade move into the areas of the chicken?

Have you ever tried this and what where the results like?

Thanks

Comment: It's a little pedantic, but the [answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/18892/1672) you're basing all this on doesn't say that freezing enlarges pores, it says that it *creates* holes in the structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That release of moisture is due to breakage of chicken's cell structure, and further moisturing will not repair it - so it's not about the pores, and there's no "going back" from that state.
Still, if You cook Your chicken in a liquid with agents that affect osmotic pressure (salt, for example), it will lead to release of liquid through membranes, and further cooling will cause the reverse effect (chcken absurbing released liquid). 
That's why stew/soup-like dishes often taste better after cooling/reheating.

Hope I got the point)

Comment: +1 You got the point ;-)  And if you add some references backing what you stated up, you'll get *more points*.

Comment: There is "going back" in some sense - as you say, the chicken can reabsorb (at least some fraction) of the water during cooking. It's mostly just in terms of texture that there's no going back.